# After decoding json value how to display the value?

Tags: php, codeigniter

In database `ProductOptions` Filed i store a json value as `{"Color":["Red","Blue","white"],"size":["L","XL"]}`. Then i get the product data from Product table.

in product detail page.

```
<?php 
   $opt =$value->ProductOptions;
   $tarray = json_decode($opt);               
}
```

After decoding the json i got the array as below

```
array (
  'size' => 
  array (
    0 => 'L',
    1 => 'XL',
  ),
  'color' => 
  array (
    0 => 'Red',
    1 => 'Blue',
    2 => 'white',
  ),
)
```

Now i want to display the option variant in product detail page.

color    Red  Blue White  (in horizontally).

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
      $data = array (
        'size' => 
              array (
                0 => 'L',
                1 => 'XL',
                    ),
        'color' => 
              array (
                  0 => 'Red',
                  1 => 'Blue',
                  2 => 'white'
                )
            );
       if(!empty($data['color'])){
      echo '<ul>';
        foreach($data['color'] as $key => $value){
              echo '<li>'.$value.'</li>';
        }             
      echo '</ul>';
      }
  ?>
```

Comment: foreach($data['color'] as $key => $value){
              echo '<li>'.$value.'</li>';
        }

Comment: for some product color will be not mention.

Comment: i modified the answer you can check now